# Separating tags with BigQuery public dataset for stackoverflow

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-public-datasets

Google makes available a public dataset for the content of Stackoverflow.  We can read about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a).  When I login to the GCP Cloud Console and visit the BigQuery page and submit the following query:

```
select id, tags from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` limit 10
```

The resulting table that is shown to me shows the tags field as concatenated items.

[image]

If I look at the JSON, I seem to see the same:

[image]

My supposition was that the tags would be delimited by the '|' character but the data seems to show otherwise.  I'm hoping to understand this better.  My end goal is to perform queries to find all questions that contain a given tag.

Comment: there is clearly something wrong with tags column there as they just simply concatenated w/o any separator - quite strange - i don't think i saw this before - even though i played few times with this dataset

Comment: Our apologies for this! Tracking here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143784150

Comment: Our apologies for this! Tracking here issuetracker.google.com/issues/143784150. In the meantime feel free to use the backup from the previous iteration of this dataset, which I left here: - https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=fh-bigquery&d=stackoverflow_archive&t=201906_posts_questions&page=table

Comment: Issue is fixed now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was discovered that an error was at play in how the source data from Stackoverflows was being transformed into BigQuery tables.  Google created an issue to resolve and eventually posted that it had been fixed.  As such, this story/posting was *transient* and likely will not be replicable nor of value in the future.

Answer (score 1):

To find all the Stackoverflow questions that contain a given tag name you can employ the SQL operator [`LIKE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators). This operator is very useful while looking for a particular pattern within a database field. It is specified after the `WHERE` statement with the following syntax:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ...
FROM table
WHERE fieldN LIKE pattern;
```

The patterns are usually written with the following wildcards that make possible to generate regular-like expressions:

- The percent symbol `"%"` looks for any string of zero or more characters.

  **Example**: `SELECT * WHERE fieldN LIKE "%foo%"` will return all the entries that contain the string "foo" in the fieldN column.
- The underscore symbol `"_"` looks for any single character.

  **Example**: `SELECT * WHERE fieldN LIKE "A_"` will return all the entries that start with the character "A".

In order to find all the Stackoverflow questions that contain a given tag `TAGNAME`, you can employ the pattern `"%TAGNAME%"`.
In this example, the query will return all the entries where the tag field contains the word "javascript":

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` 
WHERE 
  tags LIKE "%javascript%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.  It turns out that the tag data contained in BQ for Stackoverflow should be '|' delimited which would then allow us to use split to break apart the string.  Apparently the data that exists as of this moment is broken and will be repaired to return the delimited.